# MailChimp: How to collect only the country, not full address on landing page

Tags: forms, mailchimp

I'm trying to create a simple signup page for a mailing list, using MailChimp "landing pages".

I want the country of the user, but I do not want the full address. (It's a pain for a user to type it all in.)

Any way to do this, aside from a custom form, which would not automatically merge with the "Country" field of Mailchimp?